# Is there a way to see in the project level to see any VM is not having ops agent is installed in it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I want to see the list of VMs that doesn't have the **ops agent** installed in my GCP project.

Any command or API or console view will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Search "Monitoring" in gcp console, In 'Overview'--> Active Issue you will see "VMs with Ops Agent". Click "view vms" and you will get a list of all the vms with ops agent, without ops agent and other details.

Another way is go to 'Dashboards' panel below the 'Overwiew' and select VM instances from there you will also get the list.

Hope this helps!